# Naftalins big O analysis for LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, big-o

I am reading the famous book of Naftalin "Java Collections and Generics" and table 15.1 says the big o complexity of LinkedList in removal is O(1), which makes sense if there is a reference to the previous Node. All that needs to be done is to unlink the Node to be removed. 
When I check the real implementation, I see the for loop there :

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (x.item == null) {
                unlink(x);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (o.equals(x.item)) {
                unlink(x);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It looks like it searches the entire list till the element will be found. That s why it looks like the complexity is O(N). Am I missing something here?

Comment: O(1) is only for the `Iterator` (which keeps track of the current node)

Comment: As you say, `#remove(Object)` is search and remove. Perhaps you want to see `#removeLast()`, or `#unlink(Node)` inside the implementation, which do not include the search operation.

Comment: Removing a *node* is O(1), removing an *item* / *element* is O(n) since you cannot know where it is located in the list.

Comment: you are missing that you have to find the element in the list first. Indeed, the removal itself is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Lino I know, and I already remove it once I was checking the code ...